# How to change the body of text for C# .NET RequestBin HTTP API?

Tags: c#, .net, api, http

hey guys I'm new to C# and I wanted to try out Request Bin after seeing it in another youtube video, however it was a PHP video, can any of you please tell me how I can implement a body of text into the request so I can see it on the site? thank you :D here's my current code.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RequestBinExample
{
   class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
      var task = MakeRequest();
      task.Wait();

      var response = task.Result;
      var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      Console.WriteLine(body);
    }

    private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest()
    {
      var httpClient = new HttpClient();
      return await httpClient.GetAsync(new    Uri("http://requestb.in/1hui2vv1"));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = MakeRequest();
        task.Wait();

        var response = task.Result;
        var body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Console.WriteLine(body);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpContent requestContent = new StringContent("I am the message body");

        return await httpClient.PostAsync("https://requestb.in/188bhf01", requestContent);
    }
}
```

I think this should do the trick.